# Sorting the items in the RadComboBox which contains columns:

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, columnsorting

I have a RadComboBox like below :-

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox" runat="server"  EmptyMessage="Select"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" ItemsPerRequest="10" >
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 500px">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 400px">Name</td>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 100px">ID</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 500px">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 400px"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%></td>
                                <td style="width: 100px"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM table1 order by name asc" />
```

Now it is filling my `RadComboBox`.

Now i want to sort the items in my RadComboBox alphabetically when I click on the   `<HeaderTemplate>  "Name"`  and when I click on the `<HeaderTemplate> "ID"` I want to sort it numerically.

Now how to achieve this, can anyone give me any advice or help, ThankYou !

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a tough time, since this functionality isn't built in.  One idea is to add a JavaScript click event to your headers, use that to fill a hidden element.  Then check the element and apply your sort on the server.  I'll give you an idea with some pseudo-code.

```
<script>
    function Sort(field){
       //fill hidden server element with field or some indicator
       //rebind combo box with sorted data
    }
</script>

<HeaderTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 500px">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 400px" onclick="Sort('name')">Name</td>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 100px" onclick="Sort('ID')">ID</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: I tried your advice, but not successful, also new issues started comming up. Since this is not a built in functionality,  I think this is impossible !!

Comment: @JackCarothers Sorry to hear that, it's not impossible.  Just keep trying and think positive!  Good luck man.

Comment: Yes I think I can add RadGrid to the DropDown and make the Header of the added RadGrid Sortable !! That seems to be the most appropriate solution to this problem. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, if my answer was helpful please mark as accepted so I can get my imaginary internet points.